# Use Alternative Short Form (alt) in List of Acronyms

Tags: acronyms, acro

How can I make the `\printacronyms`command use the alternative short form of acronyms, alt keyword or via `\aca*{key}` command, instead of the standard short form?

This is to be used to annotate some acronyms with a *, as they have a common explanation below the list of acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion (if I have understood the question correctly). The code below needs version 3 of `acro`.

The idea is to define an additional property that I've called annotation (maybe a better name could be found). The template for the list of acronyms is then changed to print the annotation code after the short form. The rest is just suitable footnotes…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acro,scrextend}

\DeclareAcroProperty{annotate}

\RenewAcroTemplate[list]{description}{%
  \acroheading
  \acropreamble
  \begin{description}
    \acronymsmapF{
      \item[%
        \acrowrite{short}%
        \acrowrite{annotate}%
        \acroifT{alt}{/}\acrowrite{alt}%
        ]
        \acrowrite{list}%
        \acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{ (}%
        \acrowrite{foreign}%
        \acroifallT{foreign,extra}{, }%
        \acrowrite{extra}%
        \acroifanyT{foreign,extra}{)}%
        \acropagefill
        \acropages
          {\acrotranslate{page}\nobreakspace}%
          {\acrotranslate{pages}\nobreakspace}%
    }
    { \item \AcroRerun }
  \end {description}
}

\DeclareAcronym{one}{
  short = one ,
  long = first description ,
  list = first description\footnotetext{common description\label{fn:common}} ,
  annotate = \footnotemark
}
\DeclareAcronym{two}{
  short = two ,
  long = second description ,
  annotate = \footref{fn:common}
}
\DeclareAcronym{three}{
  short = three ,
  long = third description ,
  annotate = \footref{fn:common}
}
\DeclareAcronym{four}{
  short = four ,
  long = forth description
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms[display=all]

\end{document}
```

[image]